# Vb.net How to make your Application goes Sleep if not used 10 minutes or 15 minutes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a vb.net Application and I need to make my Application to go sleep if not used 10 minutes or 15 minutes? 
I am trying to use Stopwatch and Timer

//Here is the Main form load

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    StopWatch.Start()
    Tmr.Start()
End Sub
```

When the Main Form loads Stopwatch was Starting

//here is the Timer Tick

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Try
        Label2.Text = StopWatch.Elapsed.ToString
        If StopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes = 4 Then
            Sleep.Show()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I need when the Time reaches 10 Min to show the user another Form called Sleep and enter his username and password after that come back to his work and continue

[image: Pop up of the Sleep Form]

can any body help me?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What have _you_ tried? And where did you fail, with what kind of message? Please have a look at [mcve].

Comment: Seems like you already got your popup. Maybe you are instead looking for a way to detect any activity in your application and then restart the timer?

Comment: The problem is how i can count the time that user does not uses the application

Comment: Are you sure implementing this in the application is the best approach? There are already mechanisms in windows to lock the *entire workstation* due to inactivity and to require password to unlock. Why does your application need to duplicate this/more tightly constrain usage?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever This Application is School Management System so when we look our Country it needs to be more Secure because of some times the Administrator leaves the office if some thing happen such as if two students are fighting so i need to secure it

Comment: @ZADICKEDEÑ - but again, why not let *windows* lock down the entire workstation, rather than just trying to lock *your application*?

Comment: Some of the Computer are not locked down Automatically or disabled so i need my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your issue is that you want the timer to start when the user is actually AFK.

I implemented something similar a few years ago using the [IMessageFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

There's a good example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636850/vb-detect-idle-time) post.

I'd say you can just replace the

> MessageBox.Show("Time is up!")

with your

> Sleep.Show()

You may want to get rid of the ControlBox in your Sleep form, and maybe change .Show with .ShowDialog()

Hope it helps

Comment: i am trying to .ShowDialog() and that is the best way because of user can't open other forms until he enters his Username and Password but there is a problem when i change .Show to .ShowDialog()

Comment: @ZADICKEDEÑ : _"but there is a problem"_ doesn't describe anything useful. _**What**_ is the problem?

Comment: The problem is  Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box, set the form's visible property to false before calling showDialog.

Comment: I'm guessing the Tick event is fired more than once because you're missing the Timer2.Stop and Timer2.Enable = false in the Tick event. Just stop it when the Tick event is fired and start it again after the .ShowDialog() returns.

Comment: @wannabe thank you so much it works me

Comment: @wannabe : You only need to call `Timer2.Stop()` as it sets `Enabled = False` internally.

Comment: @wannabe suppose the user leaves the application and come after 9 minutes and used the Application, i need to restart the stopwatch if i use keypress , MouseClick etc  its hard because i have more Forms so what you advice to me ?

Comment: @ZADICKEDEÑ : If you use and examine the answer that wannabe linked to in his post (the second link) you'll see how it's done.

Comment: @ZADICKEDEÑ the IMessageFilter interface does that for you. Check the PreFilterMessage function content in the post I've linked before [VB Detect Idle time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636850/vb-detect-idle-time).

Comment: @ Visual Vincent thank you more and more